# Scopes in Rails. Is this a lambda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm unfamiliar with usage of lambdas. Is this one in the scope call? Or is it just a piece of syntactic sugar?

```
scope :by_frequency, -> (frequency) { where(delivery_frequency_id: frequency) }
```

Why is the frequency is parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a lambda - since Ruby 1.9 you could write a lambda in the  shorthand form you have whereas before the only syntax was this:

```
lambda {|x| 2 * x }
```

In this case the example here the argument `x` is passed in which is the equivalent of `frequency` in your example - it is a required argument for the lambda. A Ruby lambda enforces this required argument and it would complain if you called it without a value which is ideal as the where query may not make sense without it.

The whole line is syntactic sugar of Rails to allow a really nice DSL (Domain Specific Language) but all it really does is store the lambda you wrote to essentially a static method on the class. The lambda will be called when you invoke that method.

Answer (score 0):

You are largely correct, the calls to `scope`, like the one you wrote, are just syntactic sugar for writing a class method on the active record class in question.

Furthermore, It is using lambda notation in order to do so.

However, what you should keep in mind is that you are actually making a query by using the `where` keyword. It's the same as saying `ClassName.where()`

The first frequency being defined in the parenthesis following the `->` is a parameter that's being passed into the scope method being created (and then subsequently passed into `where`).

So, what you have defined is a class method that returns all instances of this object where the `delivery_frequency_id` is equal to a specific parameter.